# TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, typeerror

```
def characterName(name):
    print("What would you like to name your character?")
    name = input()
    name = str(name)

return characterName(name)

def displayIntro():
    print(name + ' are in a land full of dragons. In front of ' + name)
    print(', ' + name + ' see two caves. In one cave, the dragon is friendly')
    print('and will share his treasure with ' + name + '. The other dragon')
    print('is greedy and hungry, and will eat ' + name + ' on sight.')
    print()
```

Why does it keep giving me the type error? I'm basically trying to return the variable 'name' out of the define block so I can use it in the other blocks. The thing is, I try to mess with it a little bit and then I get the error: 'name' is not defined. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please add the [tag:python] tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is you have not called the method characterName() in displayIntro() to get the name in some variable. I don't know whether you want it like this, but below is my solution to your problem.

```
def characterName():
    print("What would you like to name your character?")
    name = input()
    name = str(name)
    return name

def displayIntro():
    name = characterName()
    print(name + ' are in a land full of dragons. In front of ' + name)
    print(', ' + name + ' see two caves. In one cave, the dragon is friendly')
    print('and will share his treasure with ' + name + '. The other dragon')
    print('is greedy and hungry, and will eat ' + name + ' on sight.')
    print()

displayIntro()
```